# PostGIS in shapefile import/export manager - how to add schema

Tags: postgis, schema

I want to know if it is possible to add the "schema" in "see connection details"
I was looking but couldn't find anything.

Comment: There's a difference between a schema and a scheme.

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: All right, thanks for the corrections, I will be more carefull the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

But you can define it when you are loading the table:

[image]

Comment: Thanks KeikkiVesanto, I don´t know how I couldn't find it my self. I though that was the description of the operation and that coudn't change, that's why i didn't test.

Comment: That @MarianoRamirez if that answers your question, you can accept the answer. Using the green tick below the voting button.

Comment: It's done Heikki*, thanks again, and by the way, nice name, here in my country we don´t have names like yours.

Comment: Thanks. No problem. happy to help.